# Apache ProxyPass to Tomcat - how to remove context path from URL?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, apache2, proxypass

I have Apache conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName project.example.com
    ServerAlias ci
    ProxyRequests Off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:1111/project

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.com/chain.pem

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

When I enter `project.example.com`, I get `https://project.example.com/project/users/sign_in` in a browser. How to remove context path from URL? 
I want to remove `project` from URL and get `https://project.example.com/users/sign_in` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the trailing slash:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:1111/project/
```

It's also a good idea to define a corresponding ProxyPassReverse:

```
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:1111/project/
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So first would be removing the context root from the application. Unless you define the context as / (blank) you cannot access the application without the context root.

This [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706950/3886428) should give you an idea of how to change the context root.
Once you are done with the steps you should be able to access your application at http://localhost:1111/.

Then coming to the httpd configuration remove the project name :

`ProxyPass / http://localhost:1111/`